# How to send attribute with onclick event in apex:tabPanel

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am trying to create a `tabpanel` and calling a javascript function with its onclick event. How do I pass the name of the selected tab to a javascript function every time a tab is clicked?

Something like:

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="Tab1" onclick="javascript:myFunction(this.selectedTab)" //something like this
     <apex:tab label="Tab1" name="Tab1" id="Tab1"> Tab1 </apex:tab>
     <apex:tab label="Tab2" name="Tab2" id="Tab2"> Tab2 </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel> 

<script type="text/javascript">
     function myFunction(tabName)
     {
        if(tabName == 'Tab1')
           do something...
         if(tabName == 'Tab2')
           do something...
     }
</script>
```

`onclick="javascript:myFunction(this.selectedTab)"`  does not work ....
How can I achieve this please ??

Comment: Do you want to pass in controller ?

Comment: I am just changing an existing page and would prefer not to add anything in controller

Comment: Anindya.. you don't have to change anything in controller but you need add variable. .. and where you want this tab Name ? in controller ?

Comment: Yes i want it in controller

Comment: Anindya.. check this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/tabpanel-switchtype-server-how-to-track-the-active-tab  also check this https://force201.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/keeping-track-of-the-selected-tab-of-an-apextabpanel-in-the-controller-using-javascript-remoting/

Answer (score 2):

When using the `switchType="client"` the `tabPanel` data is already rendered to the browser so it looks like the best event that you can hook to for detecting a tab switch is the `ontabenter` event on the `tab` itself. The `oncomplete` event is only fired on an ajax `switchType` to notify you that the ajax request & response process is finished, so that event isn't applicable here.

[Salesforce `<apex:tab />` Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tab.htm)

You can pass the DOM Id of the tab as a parameter to your function using the [`$Component.yourComponentId` syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm). The DOM Id which is rendered is the tab body, not the label (shown as a tab) though it is trivial to get a reference to the tab as shown below.

```
<script>
    function tabSwitchHandler(elementId) {
        console.log('Tab body DOM Id: ' + elementId);

        // the tab is the body DOM id suffixed by _lbl
        var tabId = elementId + '_lbl';

        // get the tab itself
        var tabLabelElement = document.getElementById(tabId);

        // get the body
        var tabBodyElement = document.getElementById(elementId);

        console.log(tabLabelElement);
        console.log(tabBodyElement);
    }
</script>

<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel">
    <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne" ontabenter="tabSwitchHandler('{!$Component.tabOne}');">content for tab one</apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo" ontabenter="tabSwitchHandler('{!$Component.tabTwo}');">content for tab two</apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```